# ARM big.LITTLE effectiveness in custom roms

Tags: custom-roms, cpu

In stock roms it's obvious that the manufacturer tries to make use of big.LITTLE technology as mush as it can (cluster managing, workload distribution etc.); I'm wandering what will happen to "these under the hood optimizations" when we install a custom rom on the phone?

For example Snapdragon 652 has 4 big cores and 4 LITTLE cores and say we flash the phone with Lineageos 14; Does Lineageos can see these two sets of core clusters separately and use them as a true big.LITTLE configuration?

Comment: I reckon that depends on the dev of individual devices. Such core dispatching options are definitely there in some custom kernels, and often their "selling point" over the original kernel of custom ROMs.